# PDO error when home page load

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

i have this code on homepage:

```
if ($interface->getsession("userid") != Null) {
    $dbh->query('Select sex `From` char `WHERE` user_id = :user');
    $dbh->bind(':user',$interface->getsession("userid"));
    $_gender = $dbh->single();
    $smarty->assign("gender",$_gender);
}
```

the userid is null and this is the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'char `WHERE` user_id = '0'' at line 1' in F:\wamp\www\StayAlive\bd\pdo.class.php on line 76

how i can resolve this?!

Comment: Why are `From` and `WHERE` wrapped in backticks?

Comment: `('Select sex From char WHERE user_id = :user')`

Comment: i was thinking that was the problem but still getting the error.

Comment: Add `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Comment: Additionally: to check whether a value is not NULL you can't use a simple comparison operator like != or =. You should use the [IS NOT NULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-not-null) operator instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though `from` and `where` are reserved words, it's [***`char`***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)  that needs to be wrapped in backticks, and not your `from` and `where`. You are selecting from the `char` table.

---

Consult the list on MySQL.com:

- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html**

---

***To further elaborate;*** had your query been, ***and as an example:***

```
('Select from From char WHERE where = :user')
```

then you would have had to use backticks around those columns and the table name:

```
('Select `from` From `char` WHERE `where` = :user')
```

I'm just mentioning this, because some do use `from` (and `to`) and other MySQL reserved words in queries for messaging systems etc. without them knowing; *it happens* (I have seen it quite a few times). We can't be expected to remember what all the reserved words are by heart, which is why checking [**the list of reserved keywords**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) is important for a developer.

***For example:***

```
('SELECT `from` FROM `tablename` WHERE `to` = :user')
```

Comment: thanks.. that was the problem.. but why still running the query when the user id was null that i don't understand...

Comment: @MárioPassos You're welcome Mário. You say *"when the user id was null"*. Your query shows as `!= Null`. If the query continued because it was null, then I'd say that would explain it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbh->query('SELECT `sex` FROM `char` WHERE `user_id` = :user');
```

Would be the proper syntaxing, you can also skip all the ` except for char, since it's an SQL syntax word.

```
$stm_getsex = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `sex` FROM `char` WHERE `user_id` = ?");
$stm_getsex->execute(array($interface->getsession("userid"));
$gender = $stm->fetchAll();

$smarty->assign("gender", $gender[0]);
```

Would be another method.